# XSLTProcessor: multiple xsl files

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I am using php XSLTProcessor to generate my html code from an xml file through an xsl file. This works.

My problem is at some point the xsl file gets too big to easily work with it, so it makes sense to distribute some parts to external files. But neither the xsl:import nor the xsl:include function works. I think the reason is probably that the xsl processor has problems with the paths, but I am not sure.

Inside my xsl file is use this:

```
<xsl:import href="2nd_file.xsl"/>
```

where *2nd_file.xsl* is in the same directory of the executing php.

I get this error:

> Warning: XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet() [xsltprocessor.importstylesheet]: compilation error: file /local/path/to/first/xsl/main.xsl line 7
>   element import in /local/path/to/php/index.php on line 57 ---- line 57
>   in the php is: $proc->importStylesheet($xslDoc);

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by "*neither the xsl:import nor the xsl:include function works*"? Show us the code you have tried.

Comment: inside my xsl file is use this: <xsl:import href="2nd_file.xsl"/> whereas this file is in the same directory of the executing php. I get this error: Warning: XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet() [<a href='xsltprocessor.importstylesheet'>xsltprocessor.importstylesheet</a>]: compilation error: file /local/path/to/first/xsl/main.xsl line 7 element import in /local/path/to/php/index.php on line 57
---- line 57 in the php is: $proc->importStylesheet($xslDoc);

Comment: Please don't post in comments - edit your question instead.

Comment: Incorporated the OPs comment into the question and editted layout/removed superflous language.

Comment: "*where 2nd_file.xsl is in the same directory of the executing php.*" I am not sure what that means. Why don't you put it in the same directory where your "main" XSLT document is?

Comment: to michael: yes, this might confuse: the original idea was that the main.xsl as well as the main.xml don't have to be inside a public directory. so they are below the / of my server. since the importing asks for an uri, the 2nd xsl could not be outside a public directory. it was rather for testing to put the 2nd file somewhere else.

Comment: @AntonHarald You can put the file anywhere you want  - but the href URI needs to be either absolute or relative to the "main" XSLT.

Comment: @michael.hor257k   ok, this is good to know, so i can keep xml and xsl files outside the public area. but: this is not working as well. when i put the 2nd_file.xsl inside the directory of my main.xsl and use the import as mentioned in the question above I get exactly the same error.

Comment: by the way: absolute path does not work as well. same error.

Comment: Based on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29097349/474189), I'm voting to close as "cannot be reproduced".

Answer (score 1):

/local/path/to/first/xsl/  is where main.xsl is but  /local/path/to/php/index.php is where your import is.  Your stylesheet will expect the root URL to be /local/path/to/first/xsl/ .  If you put the sheets to import there, it should work.

If you are using XSLT2 you can call base-uri() to show you were XSLT is working from.